# Return Sorted Array Without Modifying Original Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble with a function returning the original array as opposed to the sorted array. I tried to slice the array and return the sorted but it is not working. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
function sortArr( comparator, array ){

var newArray = array.slice();

for(var i = 0; i < newArray.size; i++)
{
    var min = i;
    for(var x = i; x < newArray.size; x++)
    {
        if(comparator(newArray[min],newArray[x]) == true)
        {
            min = x;
        }
    }

    var temp = newArray[i];
    newArray[i] = newArray[min];
    newArray[min] = temp;

}

return newArray;

}
```

I fixed the function:

```
function sortArr( comparator, array ){
    /*your code here*/
    var i, x;
    var min;
    var newArray = array.slice();

    for(i = 0; i < newArray.length - 1; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for(x = i + 1; x < newArray.length; x++)
        {
            if(comparator(newArray[min],newArray[x]) == true)
            {
                min = x;
            }
        }

        if(min != i){
            var temp = newArray[i];
            newArray[i] = newArray[min];
            newArray[min] = temp;
        }

    }

return newArray;

}
```

Comment: How is it *"not working"*? I have a feeling this question is not about avoiding mutation of the original array, but about why your sorting algorithm is not working.

Comment: `var newArray = array.slice();` This should create a copy. Step through your sorting algorithm.

Comment: I don't even see an instance where you are modifying your original array in a way that it won't maintain its integrity, I think you are having algorithm issues rather than - returning the result of the sort - issues, please clarify

Comment: I was using size instead of length and was missing an if statement.

Answer (score 7):

Copy the array with `slice` and then use native `sort`:

```
function sortArr(comparator, array) {
  return array.slice().sort(function(a,b) {
    return comparator(a,b) * 2 - 1;
  });
}
```

Comment: This assumes `comparator` returns a boolean, and converts it to `-1` or `1`. Otherwise, use `array.slice().sort(comparator)`, without conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting algorithm doesn't look quite right. For a start the swapping of values should be inside the `if` statement. I would also advise to look at @Oriol's solution which is far more elegant.

```
function sortArr( comparator, array ){

var newArray = array.slice();

for(var i = 0; i < newArray.size; i++)
{
    var min = i;
    for(var x = i; x < newArray.size; x++)
    {
        if(comparator(newArray[min],newArray[x]) == true)
        {                   
            var temp = newArray[i];
            newArray[i] = newArray[min];
            newArray[min] = temp;
            min = x;
        }
    }
}

return newArray;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
{"index.js":"var globalArray = [5, 6, 3, 2, 9];
function nonMutatingSort(arr) {
  let newArr = globalArray.slice();\n  let  emptyArr = [];
  return emptyArr.concat(newArr).sort();
}
nonMutatingSort(globalArray);"}
```

Comment: Please try to put some explanation around you answer so that it can help everyone to understand easily. In addition to that try use proper formatting for code snippet.